# Specific homework questions - too localized to be of general interest?

Tags: discussion, scope, homework-and-exercises

**Not yet another question on "level" but on "relevance"**

Should we allow **specific** homework questions like e.g.

[Homework about spinning top](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/homework-about-spinning-top)

[I lost a factor of two in the electromagnetic field tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8045/i-lost-a-factor-of-two-in-the-electromagnetic-field-tensor)

or close them as "Too Localized"?

Note: there are clearly other homework questions with a larger general value, like e.g.

[Mechanics around a rail tank wagon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/mechanics-around-a-rail-tank-wagon)

These should be kept as [discussed here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/are-puzzle-questions-appropriate).

Answer (score 5):

I favor "Too localized" for most basic homework.

Mind you, I will usually provide some hints, because I like to see people make some headway, but these "questions" suffer in at least two ways

- If we allow them we become a "homework help site" and the discourse here will be dominated by them
- They rarely address things at the level of *principles* rather than the raw mechanics of churning through a problem

Comment: The idea is to have something similar to "plzsendtehcodez" on SO

Comment: be sure to leave a comment on such questions to educate the owner and the broader community on these issues